# Facing issue while installing AWS ClusterClient with PHP 8.1 Amazon Linux 2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, memcached

I have created Elastic Beanstalk environment.

I have few config files inside my project .ebextensions folder which I had deployed on Elastic Beanstalk environment.

It includes memcached.config file as well. I have tried to download Amazon ElastiCache Cluster Client PHP 8.0/8.1 as per AWS docs

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/Appendix.PHPAutoDiscoverySetup.Installing.html#Appendix.PHPAutoDiscoverySetup.Installing.PHP7x.Ubuntu

```
wget https://elasticache-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/ClusterClient/PHP-7.4/latest-64bit-X86 --working url

wget https://elasticache-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/ClusterClient/PHP-8.0/latest-64bit-X86 --not working
```

but it's doesn't exists for php 8.0/8.1. So I have used PHP 7.4 but getting below deprecation error and memcached extension is not showing under `php -v`

```
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so: undefined symbol: zend_wrong_callback_deprecated), /usr/lib64/php/modules/amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/amazon-elasticache-cluster-client.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 8.0.20 (cli) (built: Jun 23 2022 20:34:07) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.20, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.20, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find the Cluster Client in the Amazon ElastiCache section (right at the bottom in the LHS menu).

[image]